# convert javascript event handler to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, handler, anonymous-function

I would like to convert the event handler to a jquery style click event but it doesnt seem to like passing the event through, perhaps its because its not an anonymous function anymore?

```
        // variables
        var faqOne = document.getElementById("faqOne");
        var $hiddenOne = $(".faqOneHidden");


        // javascript event handler works!
        faqOne.addEventListener("click", function(e){
        showFaqOne.showClickedFaq(e);
        }, false);
        // javascript event handle - doesnt work!
        $("#faqOne").click(function(){
            showFaqOne.showClickedFaq(e);
        });
        // constructor
        function DisplayQFaqs(link, faq){
            this.link = link;
            this.faq = faq;
        }
        // method prototype
        DisplayQFaqs.prototype.showClickedFaq = function(e){
                var el = e.currentTarget;
                if(el === this.link) {

                   this.faq.toggle("slow", function(){
                   });
                }
        };
        // new DisplayQFaqs Objects
        var showFaqOne = new DisplayQFaqs(faqOne,$hiddenOne);
```

Comment: Do you know if the handler function is called? Maybe check it by putting an alert("a"); there?

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/93bm0gs3/

Comment: The fiddle was not importing jQuery. This works - http://jsfiddle.net/93bm0gs3/2/

Answer (score 5):

Your `e` is undefined inside

```
$("#faqOne").click(function(){
        showFaqOne.showClickedFaq(e);
    });
```

Change it to

```
   $("#faqOne").click(function(e){//Now e is there
        showFaqOne.showClickedFaq(e);
    });
```